# the null-coalescing operator with return statement

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator, c#-8.0

As you can see in [C# documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/throw#the-throw-expression), we can write null coalescing operator combine with throw expression something like below

```cs
public string Name
{
    get => name;
    set => name = value ?? 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(value), message: "Name cannot be null");
}
```

But in many cases I need return statement if left value is null, for example something like below

```cs
public double CalculateSomthing(ClassType someInstance)
{
    var someValue = someInstance?.Value ?? return double.NaN;

    // Call some method
    AnyMethod(someValue);

    // Some Computation
    return someValue + 17;
}
```

But I know I could not write code something like above, my question is why? why C# language designer permit to write throw expression with null coalescing operator but don't permit use return statement with coalescing operator?

Is any intrinsic difference between them?

**Is there any near solution like above example in exist version of C#**? or I have to write some boiler plate code, something like below

```
public double CalculateSomthing(ClassType someInstance)
{

    var someValue = someInstance?.Value;
    if (someValue == null) return double.NaN;  // Boiler plate

    // Call some method
    AnyMethod(someValue);

    // Some Computation
    return someValue + 17;
}
```

Comment: You *can* write such code [since C# 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-6#null-conditional-operators). The throw expression was added in C# 7.

Comment: @LGSon OP is asking for a `return` **expression** instead of a `return` **statement**. Just like the `throw` _statement_ has been changed from C#6 to C#7 so that it can be used in places where the compiler normally expects an _expression_. They don't want to continue the method in case the first value is null, but instead of throwing only want to return. This is technically possible, but obviously nobody asked hard enough for it and no one wanted to implement, test, document and ship it.

Comment: `someValue??double.NaN` is valid. What did you try, what failed? Are you sure the problem isn't the invalid return statement after `??` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The invalid statement is what OP is asking for: a `return` expression (instead of a statement) just like there is a `throw` expression. They want to _return_ the right side value in case the left side value is null.

Comment: You can post a proposal on the C# Language GitHub page. If it makes to the Champions, maybe you'll see this feature in an upcoming language version.

Comment: @RenéVogt do you have an example of such an expression from another language, eg F#? Although in F# one would use `match` for what you describe, which points to the switch expression in C# 8. `return someInstance switch {double d=>blah,_=>double.Nan};` would be valid now

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No I don't. And the switch expression also is not exactly what OP is asking for (actually they are asking _why_ there is no return expression while the throw expression shows that it's technically possible). Well, discussing the decisions of the c# team should be left to them....I think I'd like such a feature, though I'm not sure if all this mixing and merging of expressions, operators and control flow elements really improves the language.

Comment: Voted to close as **off-topic**, as the answer to _"why C# don't permit use return statement with coalescing operator?"_ needs to come **from Microsoft**.

Comment: @RenéVogt if F#, a functional language, doesn't have such a concept is it really needed? There's no Wikipedia entry about this, so what would be an example of a useful return expression?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed it's hard to come up with a really _useful_ example. It just would be yet another syntactic sugar for (with OP's code) `if (someInstance == null) return double.Nan; var someValue = someInstance.Value;`

Comment: @sorosh_sabz do you know of *any* language that does what you describe, whatever it is? Can you give an actual usage example? The answer to your question may be "No language does this because they don't need it". Or you may be asking for a different concept entirely

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think the main usage is very similar to throw expression and useful to reduce boiler plate code like ReneVogt said in comment.

Comment: @LGSon I added another question to complete my question and prevent off-topic danger with thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Sometimes there is no substitute for an `if` statement and I would hardly call it boilerplate, any more than `?? return `... would be.

Comment: @sorosh_sabz are you sure the real question isnt' "what's the point of throw expressions"? The fact that no other language (that I know of at least) uses return expressins should be an indication that there's no advantage to it. On the contrary, it makes the code a lot **harder** to read. Exception or fault expressions on the other hand add significant value and are even indispensable, eg in pattern matching expressions. You can find them in many languages.

Answer (score 5):

[Return/break/continue expressions](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/867) *have* been discussed but are hard to implement correctly as they interfere with other constructs. At best, it's a convenience feature. As the design meeting notes say:

> This is a convenience. However, it risks a syntactic conflict with other potential futures, especially "non-local returns" (allowing a lambda to return from its enclosing method) and "block expressions" (allowing statements inside expressions). While we can imagine syntaxes for those that do not conflict, we don't want to limit the design space for them at this point, at least not for a feature that is merely "nice to have".
>
> Also, while we've been talking about this in analogy with throw expressions, that isn't quite right. throw is a dynamic effect, whereas return, break and continue are statically bound control transfers with a specific target.

As the discussion shows, it's hard to come up with a *compelling* example while there are many alternatives already.

In any case return expressions aren't similar to throw expressions. An exception is neither a control flow nor a return mechanism. It's a blown fuse that needs handling, otherwise the application can't continue.

Throw expressions aren't just convenience, they allow throwing exceptions in places where only an expression is valid. That's why they are used in functional languages like F#'s [raise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/the-raise-function) and [failwith](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/exception-handling/the-failwith-function) functions.
Without them pattern matching constructs like C#'s [switch expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions) or F#'s [match expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions) would be impossible to write and analyze at compile time.

Without throw expressions this:

```
public static RGBColor FromRainbow(Rainbow colorBand) =>
    colorBand switch
    {
        Rainbow.Red    => new RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00),
        Rainbow.Orange => new RGBColor(0xFF, 0x7F, 0x00),
        _              => throw new ArgumentException(message: "invalid enum value", paramName: nameof(colorBand)),
    };
```

Would have to be rewritten to include a dummy return statement , making analysis of the code during compilation needlessly hard. The compiler would have to recognize this patter, ignore the return statement and use the throw statement to verify whether the code is valid or not :

```
public static RGBColor FromRainbow(Rainbow colorBand) =>
    colorBand switch
    {
        Rainbow.Red    => new RGBColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00),
        Rainbow.Orange => new RGBColor(0xFF, 0x7F, 0x00),
        _              => { 
                              throw new ArgumentException(message: "invalid enum value", paramName: nameof(colorBand));
                              return default;
                          }
    };
```

That `return default` would also play havoc with C# 8's nullable reference types and nullability analysis.

C# 8 took advantage of C# 7's throw expressions to offer switch expressions. C# 9 will take advantage of both to offer discriminated unions and (hopefully) exhaustive pattern matching.